# An inequality based on inclusion of hereditary $C^*$-subalgebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra and assume that $a,b\in A_+$ are positive elements with $a\in\text{Her}(b):=\overline{bAb}$. Is it true that we can find a positive, continuous function $f\in C(\sigma(b)\cup\{0\})$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $a\le f(b)$ ?

Thoughts: First note that in case $b$ is invertible, this is easily seen to be true: write $a=\lim_n ba_nb$, so $b^{-1}ab^{-1}=\lim_na_n$. In particular $(a_n)$ is bounded, say $\|a_n\|\le M$, so $ba_nb\le Mb^2$ and taking limits yields $a\le Mb^2$, so we can take $f(t)=Mt^2$.

Also note that in the case that $b$ is a projection this is trivially true: then $\text{Her}(b)=bAb$ is unital with unit $b$, so $a=bab\le\|a\|b$.

At first, I had this question formulated for $f(t)=Mt$, i.e. can we find $M\ge0$ such that $a\le Mb$? Well, this fails easily: in $A=C[0,1]$, take $a(x)=x$ and $b(x)=x^2$. We have $a\in\text{Her}(b)$, but if $a\le Mb$, then $x\le Mx^2$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ and thus $\frac{1}{x}$ is bounded near $0$, which is false. But note that this is not a counter-example to the original question, since if we set $f(t)=t^{1/2}$ we do have $a=f(b)$ (thus $a\le f(b)$).

**Added later**: What might be a useful observation is this. Note that $\text{Her}(f(b))=\text{Her}(b)$. Indeed, we have $b\in\text{Her}(b)$ and since this is a $C^*$-algebra we have $f(b)\in\text{Her}(b)$ and thus $\text{Her}(f(b))\subset\text{Her}(b)$. On the other hand, since $f(t)\ne0$ for all $t\ne0$ we have that $\text{supp}(f^2)=\text{supp}(\text{id}_{\sigma(b)})$ (the open supports) and therefore we can find a sequence $(r_n)\subset C(\sigma(b))$ with $r_n(0)=0$ such that $\text{id}_{\sigma(b)}=\lim_n r_nf^2r_n^*=\lim_n f|r_n|^2f$. But then $b=\lim_n f(b)\cdot|r_n|^2(b)\cdot f(b)\in\text{Her}(f(b))$, so $\text{Her}(b)\subset\text{Her}(f(b))$. More on this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2226652/a-question-on-hereditary-c-subalgebras?rq=1).

**Edit 2**: The problem is also easily resolved if $0\in\sigma(b)$ is an isolated point. Then we have some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\sigma(b)\subset\{0\}\cup[\varepsilon,\|b\|]$. Set $f(0)=0$ and $f(t)=1$ for $t\in\sigma(b)\cup[\varepsilon,\|b\|]$. Then $f(b)$ is a projection and $a\in\text{Her}(b)=\text{Her}(f(b))$ so $a\le\|a\|f(b)$. So the only case left is when $0\in\sigma(b)$ is not an isolated point.

Comment: By thinking of $\overline{bAb}$ as a right $C^*(b)$-module, it follows from Cohen's factorisation theorem that $a^{1/2} = a_0 c$ for a $c\in C^*(b)$. Hence $a = c^\ast a_0^\ast a_0 c \leq \| a_0\|^2 c^\ast c$. As $\| a_0 \|^2 c^\ast c \in C^*(b)$ there is a positive $f\in C_0(\sigma(b)\setminus \{0\})$ such that $\| a_0 \|^2 c^\ast c = f(b)$.

Comment: @JamieGabe Hi, I am not familiar with $C^*$-modules but I will look these up, seems very interesting and I really appreciate this. I have to ask though, does this maybe translate to non- $C^*$-module language?

Comment: Just think of it as a right module over the $C^\ast$-algebra $C^\ast(b)$.

Comment: Essentially what you need is the following: If $A$ is a $C^\ast$-algebra and $B$ is a $C^\ast$-subalgebra of $A$, then $AB$ is closed (which follows from Cohen's factorisation theorem). In particular, if $b\in A_+$ and you take $B = C^\ast(b)$, then it easily follows that $\overline{bAb} = BAB$.  Note that this does not imply that $\overline{bAb} = bAb$, this is in general wrong.

Comment: @JamieGabe Thank you very much. I will begin studying the factorization theorem, this has been very helpful.

Comment: There's a very nice proof of Cohen's factorisation theorem in the $C^\ast$-context (due to Gert Pedersen) in the book of Brown and Ozawa. I think it's in the section on Cuntz-Pimsner algebras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning the comments into an answer: We have Cohen's factorization theorem:

> Theorem: Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra and $X$ a right Banach $A$-module. Then $XA:=\{xa:x\in X,a\in A\}\subset X$ is a closed $A$-submodule of $X$.

a slick proof of which can be found in Brown-Ozawa (theorem 4.6.4) - notice that the non-trivial part is both that $XA$ is a vector space and that it is closed.

Notice that $\text{Her}(b)\subset A\cdot C^*(b)$: indeed, we have that $\text{Her}(b):=\overline{bAb}$ and it is obvious that $bAb\subset AC^*(b)$ and by Cohen's factorization theorem, since $A$ is a right $C^*(b)$-module (since whenever $B\subset A$ is an inclusion of $C^*$-algebras, $A$ is a $B$-module), it follows that $A\cdot C^*(b)$ is a closed submodule of $A$ - in particular $\text{Her}(b)\subset A\cdot C^*(b)$.

Now let $a\in\text{Her}(b)_+$, thus $a^{1/2}\in\text{Her}(b)$, so we can write $a^{1/2}=a_0\cdot c$, where $c\in C^*(b)$. Then, $a=ca_0a_0^*c^*\le\|a_0\|^2\cdot cc^*\in C^*(b)_+$, as wanted.